# Spring boot web application starts dispatcherServlet 2 times

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When it receives first request it initiates *dispatcherServlet* 2 times. Then all requests to this app is served 2 times. It's happening on Linux only not on Windows. Log entries below:

```
[2016-01-20 10:52:39.125] boot - 3367  INFO [http-nio-8090-exec-1] --- [/]: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2016-01-20 10:52:39.125] boot - 3367  INFO [http-nio-8090-exec-1] --- [/]: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2016-01-20 10:52:39.129] boot - 3367  INFO [http-nio-8090-exec-1] --- DispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
[2016-01-20 10:52:39.129] boot - 3367  INFO [http-nio-8090-exec-1] --- DispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
[2016-01-20 10:52:39.156] boot - 3367  INFO [http-nio-8090-exec-1] --- DispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 27 ms
[2016-01-20 10:52:39.156] boot - 3367  INFO [http-nio-8090-exec-1] --- DispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 27 ms
```

App has dependency to: *spring-boot-starter-tomcat*, *spring-boot-starter-web*

It main class and controller:

```
@RestController
class LogController {

    public static final Logger LOG =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogController.class);

   @RequestMapping("/getErrors")
   public Map<String, String> getErrors() {
      //call to methods
   }
}

@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
//@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class LogAppConfiguration {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(LogAppConfiguration.class, args);
   }
}
```

I have tried removing the *EmbeddedServletContainerFactory* bean(not shown above). Still it occurs.

Comment: I doubt it is starting twice and you shouldn't need the bean. I suspect your logging is doubled.

Comment: Yes there is double logging. After I have introduced log4.properties it disappeared.